# Question on motion of vehicles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, applied-physics

What are the forces or moments reduces speed of an object while climbing?

Comment: Energy conservation. Engines have to work to gain the vehicle potential energy while going up, the vehicle can use that potential energy to accelerate while coming down.

Comment: Gravity does the job.

Answer (score 1):

While you are climbing in a sloped road, force $mg\sin\theta$ acts in opposite direction of your motion. But, while you are sliding down, that force acts in direction of your motion. For same power of vehicle (i.e. for same push on gas pedal), your speed in climbing will be less than sliding down.
[image]